# Persistent CORS Issue Despite Setting Headers in Express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cors

I'm working on a project where I have a frontend running at http://127.0.0.1:5500 and a backend Express.js server running at http://localhost:3000. I'm trying to make a POST request from the frontend to the backend but am consistently running into CORS issues.

I've tried:

Using the cors npm package to set up CORS in my Express.js server. I tried both with and without various configurations, including setting the origin to my frontend server's address and allowing credentials.

```
const corsOptions = {
    origin: 'http://127.0.0.1:5500',
    methods: 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE',
    credentials: true,
    optionsSuccessStatus: 204,
};
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.options('*', cors(corsOptions));
```

Setting the headers manually in my POST route handler:

```
app.post('/order', (req, res) => {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://127.0.0.1:5500");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    // ... (rest of the route handler)
});
```

Using curl to send OPTIONS requests to my server to inspect the headers, but I'm not seeing the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in the response, despite setting it in my server code. After everything, I'm still receiving this error in the browser console:

```
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:3000/order' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:5500' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

I'm at a complete loss as to why the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header isn't being set correctly and why I'm still running into this CORS issue. I would very highly appreciate any insight.

Comment: if you change the origin to just ```*``` does the request success ?

Comment: I would first try just `app.use(cors());`, remove `app.options('*', cors(corsOptions));` and remove the two `res.header` - i.e. start from a basic setup - it should work - I've never had to do any more than that for an API that can be accessed from anywhere. Once that works, then you can limit `origin: 'http://127.0.0.1:5500'` if you want